# Singleton in Cython handled by classmethod

Tags: python, python-2.7, singleton, cython

This is a question following by the answer from [Singleton is not working in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245056/singleton-is-not-working-in-cython?noredirect=1#comment89484867_51245056)

The solution from the above link works when MyCythonClass do not have any attritbute to be initialize.

The solution doesnt seem to be working if i have attributes to cinit my myCythonClass.

I am quite new to Cython and C, any help is appreciated.

```
cdef class Singleton:
    _instances = {}
    @classmethod
    def instance(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

cdef class MyCythonClass(Singleton):
    cdef int apple, orange
    def __cinit__(self, int apple, int orange):
        self.apple = apple
        self.orange = orange
    pass

c = MyCythonClass(1,2).instance()
d = MyCythonClass(3,4).instance()
e = c is d  # True

print 'res=', e
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    c = MyCythonClass().instance(1,2)
  File "testing.pyx", line 12, in testing.MyCythonClass.__cinit__
    def __cinit__(self, int apple, int orange):
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: You need to omit the parentheses after MyCythonClass and pass the parameters to the instance method, I.e. MyCythonClass.instance(1,2).

Comment: Thanks a lot Till, looks like a very stupid questions i was asking, I wasnt familiar with classmethod